# how to add horizontal line between text

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

Night now I have two text response from my backend and I'm wondering how can I make look like the design below. I'm not sure if that might be possible but any suggestion or help will be really appreciated.

I just wanna add automatically a horizontal line to separate text if there are two or more broadcast instead of showing on the same line like right now(pic).

```
    <mat-card class="alert" *ngIf="broadcastNotifications?.length">
      <mat-card-title *ngFor="let broadcast of broadcastNotifications">
          <p style="font-size: 15px; color: black; margin-top: 25px;">{{broadcast.message}}</p>
      </mat-card-title>
    </mat-card>
```

```
    this.notificationService.getNotification().subscribe((response: any) => {
      if(response && response.length){
        const alerts = response.filter(el => el.notificationType === 2);
        this.broadcastNotifications = response.filter(el => el.notificationType === 1);
        if(alerts.length){
          this.dialog.open(ReleaseDialogComponent, {
            data : {notifications: alerts}
          });
        }
      }
    })
```

What it look like right now vs what I thinking about doing it.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: The html `<hr />` displays a horizontal line, that's a starting point

Comment: hi can you show me where exactly should i be placing. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<mat-divider>` for this purpose.
Move the for loop to an `ng-container` and add `<mat-divider>` for all the element which is not the last one.

```js
<mat-card class="alert" *ngIf="broadcastNotifications?.length">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let broadcast of broadcastNotifications; let i = index">
        <mat-card-title>
            <p style="font-size: 15px; color: black; margin-top: 25px;">{{broadcast.message}}</p>
        </mat-card-title>
    <mat-divider *ngIf="broadcastNotifications.length - 1 !== i"></mat-divider>
    </ng-container>
</mat-card>
```

Example can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-1px3pd?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: You can replace the mat-divider with <hr /> as well